# I know some html and css as a novice. How do I use more than 1 jQuery plugin together in harmony?

Tags: jquery, plugins

First off, sorry if I am not in the right place. I don't know jQuery but found these cool plugins for my html. Sadly, I find that using multiple plugins causes conflict and they do not work properly. My first plugin had documentation to copy a snippet of noConflict code into a js file, which helped as I finally figured that out. I found that arranging the order of the script code in the body element helped. But one of my plugins is still a little off. I found answers but only for people who know javascript.

Do I need to hire someone on Freelancer or here to change javascript code to make this work or is there some easy copy & paste method where I can paste something like:

($Make it all work right)

somewhere in my code? That's my question. The plugins I am using are a fader, a menu, and another plugin to embiggen things. I have them all working perfectly, except the embiggen things plugin is missing some images in the drop down menu and the thumb-tack icon in the insta-pear/disappear image information box. Thanks!!!

Comment: Most jQuery plugins won't conflict each other, as long as their name is different (and almost all does). Can you post what plugins (better with web site) you using? BTW, how you know they conflicted?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us some code? If you write jQuery plugins correctly, there shouldn't be any conflicts. Here's a tutorial on one to write one: http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html
Pay close attention to the send part of Step 1. It'll show you how to wrap your plugin code so that it won't conflict with other scripts.

Another thing to keep in mind is to learn some Javascript basics like scope and closures. Here's a tutorial for one: http://elegantcode.com/2010/10/22/basic-javascript-part-1-functions/
It'll help you understand how to write code that might have similar variable names but not have them conflict.